# Spring Boot 2.3.15 version upgrade : RedisTemplate is not working like earlier

Tags: spring-boot

Spring boot 2.3.15 version upgrade error with RedisTemplate

```
[org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/health/HealthEndpointConfiguration.class]: 
Bean instantiation via factory method failed; 
nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthContributorRegistry]: Factory method 'healthContributorRegistry' threw exception; 
nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'redisHealthContributor' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/redis/RedisReactiveHealthContributorAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; 
nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.ReactiveHealthContributor]: Factory method 'redisHealthContributor' threw exception; 
nested exception is 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Beans must not be empty
```

Comment: My setup is :
---------------
 PCF Services --> Services --> MyRedisInstance  <br><br>
 manifest.yml  and manifest-dev.yml--> Will have the PCF service redis instance

Comment: @Repository   <br>
    private class UserRepository   <br>
    {  
      private HashOperations hashOperations;
    
    public UserRepository(RedisTemplate redisTemplate) {
    this.hashOperations = redisTemplate.opsForHash();
    }
    
    public myDTO getDataById {
    
    {
            myDTO valuesFromRedisHash = new myDTO();
    
            try {
                valuesFromRedisHash = (myDTO) hashOperations.get("ACTUALHASHNAME", id);
             }
    }

Comment: Please add the code to the original question and use some formatting tags to make it readable. If you have any doubts please refer https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help